# Apache Drill failed to connect to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-drill

This is my hdfs version:

> NameNode '10.207.78.21:38234'
>
> Started:   Mon Feb 02 19:16:43 CST 2015
>
> Version:   1.0.4, r1393290

This is the config of drill file system plugin:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "hdfs://10.207.78.21:38234",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "root": {
    "location": "/",
    "writable": false,
    "defaultInputFormat": null
  },
  "tmp": {
    "location": "/tmp",
    "writable": true,
    "defaultInputFormat": null
  }
},
"formats": ...
```

This is my test data:

```
bash-4.3$ ./hadoop fs -cat /test
{"key": "value"}
```

And drill failed executing a query in embedded mode:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> SELECT * FROM rpmp.`/test` LIMIT 20;
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: EOFException


[Error Id: fd784c1a-8353-430a-9ae3-08a5154755fe on xxx.com:31010]

  (org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.ForemanException) Unexpected exception during fragment initialization: Failed to create schema tree: End of File Exception between local host is: "xxx.com/10.95.112.80"; destination host is: "yyy.com":38234; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException
    org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run():262
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker():1145
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run():615
    java.lang.Thread.run():745
  Caused By (org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.DrillRuntimeException) Failed to create schema tree: End of File Exception between local host is: "xxx.com/10.95.112.80"; destination host is: "yyy.com":38234; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException
    org.apache.drill.exec.ops.QueryContext.getRootSchema():169
    org.apache.drill.exec.ops.QueryContext.getRootSchema():151
    ...
```